# how to show that this non-linear operator is a contraction

Tags: functional-analysis, contraction-operator

Let:

> $$ Tf(t):=\gamma(t)+k\int_0^t\cos(f(t)-f(s))\,ds. $$

How can we show/discuss whether this linear operator is a contraction for some particular $k?$

I proceed by normal step but do not know how to deal with the cosine:

> $$ \\||Tg-Tf||\le|k| \int_0^t||\cos(g(t)-g(s))-\cos(f(t)-f(s))||\,ds. $$

I'm stuck here.
Please help!

Comment: I'm not convinced that this operator is linear, as the cosine seems to spoil it! What space does $T$ operate on?

Comment: sorry it is none linear  T is from C to C I guess. The problem is rather vague. it just states  some sort of ' discuss this problem with suitable settings.'

Comment: What is $k$? For $k = 0$ it is clearly a contradiction. Otherwise, it might help to use that the cosine is Lipschitz with constant $1$, i.e., $|\cos(x) - \cos(y)| \le |x - y|$.